# Boot failed - frozen with Ubuntu 19.10 - error message "Kernel panic"

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed and I rebooted and got error message even after rebooting: 
"2.751842 Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)
2.752751 end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)"

I tried putting installation dvd in and rebooting - nothing, i.e. same message.

Any ideas what I can do? Thanks

Comment: Grub menu won’t let me move highlighted bar down using arrows

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I got it working finally using my installation dvd

Comment: You originally indicated that you got the same error booting to either the computer, or the installation DVD. What changed? What steps did you take to resolve the problem?

Comment: I’m not really sure- the first time it didn’t work using the DVD but the second it did

Comment: So you finally got the DVD to boot... what did you do then?

Comment: I had a coffee?

Comment: You said "*I got it working finally using my installation dvd*"... so my question was about what you did to finally get it working. Did you reinstall?